# Detect when new HTML tags are added to DOM using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I am making a JavaScript library which using special link tags I made. Right now, the library is using the tags only after the page loads and I want that if the developer adds more tags using the JavaScript HTML DOM it will work too. Is there any event which will get fired when new tags are added?

Comment: For example, if the developer is using the setTimeout function and adding the special tag after 4 minutes for example after the page loads. How can i detect that a new tag was added?

Comment: I tried the mutation api and its not working. can someone please an example of how to detect when a new node is inserted ONLY with JavaScript?